# How to switch from Modern Times to normal?

Tags: tropico-4

How can I switch from Modern Times to normal campaign? I played some classic campaign and 
then I tried Modern Times and now I want to switch back to normal.

Comment: Are you running the Steam Beta client?

Comment: No,I am running the classic steam client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play the original campaign, click "Play" on the main menu, then click "Campaign". You'll keep your original character and mission progress.

To play Sandbox mode without Modern Times, there is an option to disable it when setting the difficulty.